# Mach's conjecture and the twin paradox in an empty universe

Tags: general-relativity, special-relativity, reference-frames, observers, machs-principle

What would happen if we revisit the twin paradox in an empty universe? Indeed, according to [Mach's principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mach%27s_principle), when a spaceship accelerates in our universe filled with too many stars and other objects, the observer in the cabin can claim that half of the universe is accelerated towards and the other half is accelerated away from him, and thus some kind of gravitational field is induced in the cabin since the local inertial frames are affected by the cosmic motion and distribution of matter.

However, if we consider the universe to be empty of stars and other objects, and if there exist only two spaceships, locating side by side, in each of which one of the twins is located, and if one twin starts up his own spaceship and accelerates away from the other twin, then the other twin would automatically feel a similar acceleration to that in the other spaceship because, to him, the only external object is his bro's accelerating spaceship. Therefore, if he uses Mach's principle, he can deduce that though he never starts up his own spaceship, the accelerating motion of this bro's spaceship as the only detectable external (celestial) body would induce acceleration in his cabin.

Since these accelerations are symmetrically similar, the time dilations, predicted by SR, that each twin attributes to the other one is similar as well as those time rates predicted by GR. Is not the twin paradox revived in this case without breaking the symmetry through the traveling twin's acceleration?

Comment: Mach's principle usually refers to rotating frames.

Comment: How would the spaceship accelerate in universe with conservation of momentum? The only way is to throw away some momentum somehow. It seems to me you forgot this lost momentum to take into an account. Even thought the spaceship accelerates, the center of mass of spaceship+exhaust gass remains stationary.

Comment: The twin paradox is usually explained in Minkowski spacetime, which is actually empty. Acceleration is not needed for the explanation.

Comment: @Umaxo:  that's not an unreasonable answer to the question, to be honest.